# getting a corresponding value from a list in excel

Tags: excel

I have a price list for the ingredients used for cooking food in my catering company. The list has two columns; one for the ingredients and one for unit costs. Think it like a database.

There is an another excel datasheet i've made for cost analysis. For each meal, i write down the ingredients, the amount used, and unit cost. How should i automate the process? I write down the ingredient, and excel should get the corresponding unit cost from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `VLOOKUP` formula to pull the cost of the particular ingredient from the other sheet.

Let's say that the sheet containing the price list is called `Sheet1` with column A having the ingredients and column B the corresponding cost, and that the ingredient in your cost analysis data sheet is found in cell `A1`. Using this will get you the price of this ingredient:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

This takes `A1`, looks for it in column A, and returns the value from the second column (hence why the `2`). `FALSE` indicates that the looking up is exact; only cells exactly matching will be returned.

If the cost of the ingredient was in column C instead, you'd use A:C as range and `3` to get the cost.